# Loop until it finds a string

Tags: loops, while-loop, tcl, expect

I need to write a script that will configure some network devices.

It logs in to the device through ssh, then it lists all available ports and devices connected to them. In order to properly configure the device I need to click space (space = show next page) until I find a new device connected to one of the ports. The best way to find it would be to search for the "NEW" string on each page. Unfortunately I don't know how to write such a loop.

Comment: So far I've written a C++ program that searches for a new device connected to one of the ports. The problem however remains unsolved. I still don't know how to do that in TCL.

Answer (score 0):

To make an expect script detect a prompt to “press <kbd>Space</kbd> for more”, you need to use something like this:

```
expect {
    "Press space for more..." {
        send " "
        exp_continue;            # <<< Magic! Keep this expect going!
    }
    "theRealDataEnd!" {
        # this can be empty
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to do more work to save off the contents of the `expect_out(buffer)` variable as well.